# Acer Aspire One 725

Tags: performance, aspire-one

I recently got an Acer Aspire One 725 and I want to install Ubuntu on it.
I tried Ubuntu 13.10 32-bit and 64-bit, but I got a lot of errors, and it is running a little slowly. Has anyone tried to install Ubuntu on this netbook which I prefer?

Please help, it will be very helpful!

Here is a [link](http://www.cnet.com/products/acer-aspire-one-725-0802-11-6-c-60-windows-7-home-premium-64-bit-2-gb-ram-320-gb-hdd/specs/) to my netbook's specifications.

Comment: Your netbook specs are OK for running Ubuntu. You need to search the Dash for _Additional Drivers_, click the Additional Drivers icon to open the Additional Drivers window, click the ATI/AMD graphics driver that has [Recommended] after it to select it, click the **Activate** button to install the [Recommended] graphics driver, and reboot the netbook to enable the graphics driver.

Comment: Did you check the MD5 checksum of the downloaded ISO to make sure it arrived intact? Yes or no?

Answer (score 0):

though quite late in replying, maybe this will be useful to someone.

I have been and still am using an Acer Aspire One 725 with C60. it was working ok with 2GB RAM, though I have upgraded this to 8GB RAM.

I've had issues with the wifi driver, sound, SD card reader, screen brightness, and some function buttons when I first bought it. however, all issues have been solved quite some time ago by the community and incorporated into the kernel. Now, everything works out of the box.

Just checked, only the zoom of the touchpad is not working, I may have disabled it some time ago. not sure. two finger scrolling works.